# Modal Lightbox - Images Repeat

Tags: image, lightbox, modal-dialog, repeat, slimbox

http://gisave.com/index.php/gisave-purchase

This happens in other parts of my site, but check here, go into a category and click on a product image.  For some reason the images repeat four or more times, cascading vertically.  Checking the code it seems that the image code is just being repeated.  How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant, and may have only been my own simple oversight, but when my images kept repeating it was because I forgot to close my `<a>` tags, so right before the closing div tag, I placed my closing `</a>` tag and now it works fine.

```
<div id="logo">< a href="index.html">< img src="Website images/logo.png"/>***< /a>***< /div>
```